# What files does the Linux kernel access?

Tags: files, linux-kernel

`/init` during early userspace, `/sbin/init`, and `/sbin/request-key` are three files that the Linux kernel accesses (and they are all executables). Are there any other files, possibly non-executable ones, that Linux opens? Like maybe the files containing the names of the users on a system?

Comment: Linux operates on *a lot* of files. Are you asking about a particular process?

Comment: @dr01 I'm pretty sure OP is talking about the Linux kernel itself. And only ones it does itself, not at request of e.g., a userspace program calling `open(2)`.

Comment: @derobert Thanks, it makes more sense now.

Comment: Why do you ask? Are you considering a non-conventional file tree? Some file paths are hardcoded inside `libc.so`

Answer (score 4):

In general, a Linux kernel doesn't open files on its own behalf (rather than on behalf of processes).  Even `/sbin/init` (or the 'init' program specified on the kernel command line) is `exec()`ed by a process (process 1 is constructed directly from an image inside the kernel, IIRC).

At one time, kernel modules requiring firmware would directly open the firmware files, but this is no longer the case, and instead the kernel makes requests of a user-mode helper program.

If your question is about which filenames are compiled into the Linux kernel, then we see the following in the 'init' image that seeds process 1:

```
/init
/sbin/init
/etc/init
/bin/init
/bin/sh
/dev/console
```

A recursive grep for `"/` turns up quite a few hits; mostly false-positives, but worth looking through for real matches.

Comment: But you're splitting hairs.  The fact that process 1 is constructed from an image in the kernel is an important part of this discussion, and should not be relegated to a parenthetical note.  Process 1 is a sockpuppet for the kernel (at least up until the `exec` succeeds); it is acting as a proxy for the kernel.  I believe that the spirit and intent of the question is "What filesystem pathnames are hard-coded into the \*nix kernel?", and `/sbin/init` clearly answers that question (even if the pathname is obfuscated in the embedded, pre-compiled byte code that the kernel uses to seed process 1).

Answer (score 3):

Regarding user names, the kernel don't need (and don't care about) them, since it is dealing only with *numerical* user ids (the uid 0, a.k.a. `root`, may have special status). See [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) & [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html)

Conversion from user names to user ids is done by `libc` functions like [getpwnam(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwnam.3.html). The `libc` may access files (notably `/etc/passwd`) for that, see [nsswitch.conf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html)

Regarding opening files from inside the kernel outside of an existing process (which uses [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)...) AFAIK the kernel is only starting *few* processes from `/sbin/init` (or else `/bin/sh`), `/sbin/request-key`, `/sbin/tomoyo-init`, `/sbin/modprobe`, `/sbin/poweroff`, etc... You might get the full list by using `strings` on the uncompressed `vmlinux` kernel file.

Notice also that several files paths are hardcoded in the dynamic loader (see [ld-linux(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html) etc...) or the standard C library (your `libc.so`) so practically needed for nearly all applications.

Comment: I think `udev` also has some kernel-triggered processes.